# Conditional sampling in each row of a matrix using R

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I am trying to sample from something similar to the matrix created by the following code:

```
    set.seed(17)
    x = sample(0:1, 100, replace=T)
    x = matrix(x, 20)
    xrowsum = apply(x, 1, sum)
    x = x[xrowsum > 2, ]
    x
    #      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
    # [1,]    0    1    1    0    1
    # [2,]    1    1    1    1    0
    # [3,]    1    1    1    0    1
    # [4,]    0    1    1    0    1
    # [5,]    0    1    1    0    1
    # [6,]    1    1    0    0    1
    # [7,]    1    1    1    0    1
    # [8,]    1    1    1    0    0
    # [9,]    1    0    1    1    1
    #[10,]    1    1    1    1    1
    #[11,]    1    1    0    1    1
```

The goal is to sample two items from each row, but only those entries equal to 1, and assign 0 to the rest of the row. One expected result might look like this.

```
    #      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
    # [1,]    0    1    1    0    0
    # [2,]    1    0    0    1    0
    # [3,]    1    0    0    0    1
    # [4,]    0    1    0    0    1
    # [5,]    0    1    0    0    1
    # [6,]    0    1    0    0    1
    # [7,]    0    1    1    0    0
    # [8,]    1    0    1    0    0
    # [9,]    1    0    0    1    0
    #[10,]    0    0    1    1    0
    #[11,]    0    1    0    0    1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution using `apply`.

```
t(apply(x, 1, function(row) {
   out <- rep(0, length(row))
   one.idx <- which(row == 1)
   stopifnot(length(one.idx) >= 2)
   keep.idx <- sample(one.idx, 2)
   out[keep.idx] <- 1
   out
}))
```

It will error out if a row has less than two `1`. Please clarify if this is not how you want to handle that particular case.